# HTML Zoom messing up aspect ratio

Tags: css, html, zooming, aspect-ratio

1) The right element (Now Playing), is not able to be moved down where I need it (aligned with the news)

2) The aspect ratio of the (Now Playing) element is messed up when someone zooms in or out, how can I preserve this?

Here is the code:

HTML: http://pastebin.com/qiGPzpAk CSS: http://pastebin.com/T8e8pXjv

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: May I advise you to use http://jsfiddle.net for demos?

Comment: Could you upload your images for us to download them? E.g. http://imgur.com/

Comment: What do you mean by aligned with the news? Could you provide a quick sketch picture? Based on the code you want to stick it to the right side, at the moment.